# Plotting matrix values from an interval

Tags: r, data-analysis

I have a matrix of many-many scaled values. It's a (2x500000) matrix.

I need to plot the matrix limited on [0.5, 0.6] × [0.0, 0.1]. And every column of the resulting matrix is interpreted as a point in R^2.

Could you tell me please, doest it mean, that my columns must be vectors like (0.502, 0.098), (0.534, 0.0423) etc.?

If yes, how can I subset exactly that kind of columns (part of the matrix)?

Thank you very much in advance for your help!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If your matrix is `mat`, this will subset the columnas that you want:

```
mat[,which(mat[1,] >= 0.5 &
           mat[1,] <= 0.6 & 
           mat[2,] >= 0 & 
           mat[2,] <= 0.01)]
```